# fortran 90 (floating point error: overflow)

Tags: floating-point, fortran90

i am dealing with the code below and i am recieving 'runtime error M6104:MATH floating point error:overflow'. i searched the error online and it is written the output values have high range than input values that i represent as input. I am using Microsoft Developer Studio and since my computer 64-bit when i debugged the program shut down. So, i couldn't see which lines create problems. If you examine the code and give me any clue about what is the problem, i will be extremely pleased.

The code;

```
! computer code for lid-driven cavity
parameter (n=100,m=100)
real f(0:8,0:n,0:m)
real rho(0:n,0:m)
real w(0:8), cx(0:8),cy(0:8)
real u(0:n,0:m), v(0:n,0:m)
integer i
real tminv(0:8,0:8),sm(0:8),tm(0:8,0:8),stmiv(0:8,0:8)
real ev(0:8,0:8)
open(2,file='uvfield')
open(3,file='uvely')
open(4,file='vvelx')  
open(8,file='timeu')
open(10,file='tmat')
w(:)=(/4./9.,1./9.,1./9.,1./9.,1./9.,1./36.,1./36.,1./36.,1./36./)
cx(:)=(/0.,1.,0.,-1.,0.,1.,-1.,-1.,1./)
cy(:)=(/0.,0.,1.,0.,-1.,1.,1.,-1.,-1./)
tm(0,:)=(/1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0/)
tm(1,:)=(/-4.,-1.,-1.,-1.,-1.,-2.0,-2.0,-2.0,-2.0/)
tm(2,:)=(/-4.0,-2.,-2.,-2.,-2.,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0/)
tm(3,:)=(/0.0,1.0,0.0,-1.,0.0,1.0,-1.,-1.,1.0/)
tm(4,:)=(/0.0,-2.,0.0,2.0,0.0,1.0,-1.,-1.,1.0/)
tm(5,:)=(/0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,-1.,1.0,1.0,-1.,-1.0/)
tm(6,:)=(/0.0,0.0,-2.,0.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,-1.,-1./)
tm(7,:)=(/0.0,0.0,-1.,1.0,-1.,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0/)
tm(8,:)=(/0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,-1.,1.0,-1./)
a1=1./36.
tminv(0,:)=(/4.*a1,-4.*a1,4.*a1,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0./)
tminv(1,:)=(/4.*a1,-a1,-2.*a1,6.*a1,-6.*a1,0.,0.,9.*a1,0.0/)
tminv(2,:)=(/4.*a1,-a1,-2.*a1,0.,0.0,6.*a1,-6.*a1,-9.*a1,0.0/)
tminv(3,:)=(/4.*a1,-a1,-2.*a1,-6.*a1,6.*a1,0.,0.,9.*a1,0.0/)
tminv(4,:)=(/4.*a1,-a1,-2.*a1,0.,0.,-6.*a1,6.*a1,-9.*a1,0./)
tminv(5,:)=(/4.*a1,2.*a1,a1,6.*a1,3.*a1,6.*a1,3.*a1,0.,9.*a1/)
tminv(6,:)=(/4.*a1,2.*a1,a1,-6.*a1,-3.*a1,6.*a1,3.*a1,0.,-9.*a1/)
tminv(7,:)=(/4.*a1,2.*a1,a1,-6.*a1,-3.*a1,-6.*a1,-3.*a1,0.,9.*a1/)
tminv(8,:)=(/4.*a1,2.*a1,a1,6.*a1,3.*a1,-6.*a1,3.*a1,0.,-9.*a1/)
do i=0,8
do j=0,8
sumcc=0.0
do l=0,8
sumcc=sumcc+tminv(i,l)*tm(l,j)
end do
ev(i,j)=sumcc
end do
end do
do i=0,8
print*,(ev(i,j),j=0,8)
end do

uo=0.05
rhoo=1.00
dx=1.0
dy=dx
dt=1.0
alpha=0.001
Re=uo*m/alpha
print*,"Re=",Re
omega=1.0/(3.*alpha+0.5)
tau=1./omega

sm(:)=(/1.0,1.4,1.4,1.0,1.2,1.0,1.2,tau,tau/)
do i=0,8
do j=0,8
stmiv(i,j)=tminv(i,j)*sm(j)

end do
end do
do i=0,8
print*,(stmiv(i,j),j=0,8)
end do

mstep=1000
do j=0,m
do i=0,n
rho(i,j)=rhoo
u(i,j)=0.0
v(i,j)=0.0
end do
end do
do i=1,n-1
u(i,m)=uo
v(i,m)=0.0
end do
!main loop
do kk=1,mstep
call collesion(u,v,f,rho,n,m,tm,stmiv)
call streaming (f,n,m)
! ---------------
call sfbound(f,n,m,uo)
call rhouv(f,rho,u,v,cx,cy,n,m)
print*,u(0,m/2),v(0,m/2),rho(0,m/2),u(n,m/2),v(n,m/2),rho(n,m/2)
write(8,*)kk,u(n/2,m/2),v(n/2,m/2)
END DO
!end of main loop
call result(u,v,rho,uo,n,m)
stop
end
!end of main program

subroutine collesion(u,v,f,rho,n,m,tm,stmiv)
real f(0:8,0:n,0:m)
real rho(0:n,0:m)
real u(0:n,0:m), v(0:n,0:m)
real tm(0:8,0:8),stmiv(0:8,0:8)
real fmom(0:8,0:n,0:m),fmeq(0:8,0:n,0:m)
!calculate equilibrium moments
do i=0,n
do j=0,m
t1=u(i,j)*u(i,j)+v(i,j)*v(i,j)
fmeq(0,i,j)=rho(i,j)
fmeq(1,i,j)=rho(i,j)*(-2.0+3.0*rho(i,j)*t1)
fmeq(2,i,j)=rho(i,j)*(1.0-3.0*rho(i,j)*t1)
fmeq(3,i,j)=rho(i,j)*u(i,j)
fmeq(4,i,j)=-rho(i,j)*u(i,j)
fmeq(5,i,j)=rho(i,j)*v(i,j)
fmeq(6,i,j)=-rho(i,j)*v(i,j)
fmeq(7,i,j)=rho(i,j)*(u(i,j)*u(i,j)-v(i,j)*v(i,j))
fmeq(8,i,j)=rho(i,j)*u(i,j)*v(i,j)
end do
end do
!calculate moments
do i=0,n
do j=0,m
do k=0,8
suma=0.0
do l=0,8
suma=suma+tm(k,l)*f(l,i,j)
end do
fmom(k,i,j)=suma
end do
end do
end do
!collision in the moment space  
do i=0,n
do j=0,m
do k=0,8
sumb=0.0
do l=0,8
sumb=sumb+stmiv(k,l)*(fmom(l,i,j)-fmeq(l,i,j))
end do
f(k,i,j)=f(k,i,j)-sumb
end do
end do
end do
return
end
subroutine streaming(f,n,m)
real f(0:8,0:n,0:m)
! streaming
DO j=0,m
DO i=n,1,-1 !RIGHT TO LEFT
f(1,i,j)=f(1,i-1,j)
END DO
DO i=0,n-1 !LEFT TO RIGHT
f(3,i,j)=f(3,i+1,j)
END DO
END DO
DO j=m,1,-1 !TOP TO BOTTOM
DO i=0,n
f(2,i,j)=f(2,i,j-1)
END DO
DO i=n,1,-1
f(5,i,j)=f(5,i-1,j-1)
END DO
DO i=0,n-1
f(6,i,j)=f(6,i+1,j-1)
END DO
END DO
DO j=0,m-1 !BOTTOM TO TOP
DO i=0,n
f(4,i,j)=f(4,i,j+1)
END DO
DO i=0,n-1
f(7,i,j)=f(7,i+1,j+1)
END DO
DO i=n,1,-1
f(8,i,j)=f(8,i-1,j+1)
END DO
END DO
return
end
subroutine sfbound(f,n,m,uo)
real f(0:8,0:n,0:m)
do j=0,m
! bounce back on west boundary
f(1,0,j)=f(3,0,j)
f(5,0,j)=f(7,0,j)
f(8,0,j)=f(6,0,j)
! bounce back on east boundary
f(3,n,j)=f(1,n,j)
f(7,n,j)=f(5,n,j)
f(6,n,j)=f(8,n,j)
end do
! bounce back on south boundary
do i=0,n
f(2,i,0)=f(4,i,0)
f(5,i,0)=f(7,i,0)
f(6,i,0)=f(8,i,0)
end do
! moving lid, north boundary
do i=1,n-1
rhon=f(0,i,m)+f(1,i,m)+f(3,i,m)+2.*(f(2,i,m)+f(6,i,m)+f(5,i,m))
f(4,i,m)=f(2,i,m)
f(8,i,m)=f(6,i,m)+rhon*uo/6.0
f(7,i,m)=f(5,i,m)-rhon*uo/6.0
end do
return
end
subroutine rhouv(f,rho,u,v,cx,cy,n,m)
real f(0:8,0:n,0:m),rho(0:n,0:m),u(0:n,0:m),v(0:n,0:m),cx(0:8),cy(0:8)
do j=0,m
do i=0,n
ssum=0.0
do k=0,8
ssum=ssum+f(k,i,j)
end do
rho(i,j)=ssum
end do
end do
do i=1,n
rho(i,m)=f(0,i,m)+f(1,i,m)+f(3,i,m)+2.*(f(2,i,m)+f(6,i,m)+f(5,i,m))
end do
DO i=1,n
DO j=1,m-1
usum=0.0
vsum=0.0
DO k=0,8
usum=usum+f(k,i,j)*cx(k)
vsum=vsum+f(k,i,j)*cy(k)
END DO
u(i,j)=usum/rho(i,j)
v(i,j)=vsum/rho(i,j)
END DO
END DO
return
end
subroutine result(u,v,rho,uo,n,m)
real u(0:n,0:m),v(0:n,0:m)
real rho(0:n,0:m),strf(0:n,0:m)
open(5, file='streamf')
! streamfunction calculations
strf(0,0)=0.
do i=0,n
rhoav=0.5*(rho(i-1,0)+rho(i,0))
if(i.ne.0) strf(i,0)=strf(i-1,0)-rhoav*0.5*(v(i-1,0)+v(i,0))
do j=1,m
rhom=0.5*(rho(i,j)+rho(i,j-1))
strf(i,j)=strf(i,j-1)+rhom*0.5*(u(i,j-1)+u(i,j))
end do
end do
! 
write(2,*)"VARIABLES =X, Y, U, V, S"
write(2,*)"ZONE ","I=",n+1,"J=",m+1,",","F=BLOCK"
do j=0,m
write(2,*)(i,i=0,n)
end do
do j=0,m
write(2,*)(j,i=0,n) 
end do
do j=0,m
write(2,*)(u(i,j),i=0,n)
end do
do j=0,m
write(2,*)(v(i,j),i=0,n)
end do
do j=0,m
write(2,*)(strf(i,j),i=0,n)
end do
do j=0,m
write(3,*)j/float(m),u(n/2,j)/uo,u(3*n/4,j)/uo
end do
do i=0,n
write(4,*) i/float(n),v(i,m/2)/uo
end do
return
end
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but i dont want you to read all of this, i put it all cause you can copy-paste the code and debug it and give me any clue what could be the problem? Cause i cannot debug with developer studio.

Comment: You have to let us know where the error is. Compile in debug mode and run. It will tell you which source line causes the error in the console window.

Comment: That's my problem. When i compile in debug mode, the program gives and error and shuts down. So, i couldn't learn which line creates error, that's why i would be please if anyone can copy paste the code and debug, at least i can learn which line cause to problem. I am trying to find Fortran90 which can work on 64-bit system but, by the way i need to solve this problem.

Comment: real stmiv(0:8,0:8)
    real fmom(0:8,0:n,0:m),fmeq(0:8,0:n,0:m)
    do i=0,n
    do j=0,m
    do k=0,8
    sumb=0.0
    do l=0,8
    sumb=sumb+stmiv(k,l)*(fmom(l,i,j)-fmeq(l,i,j))
    end do
    f(k,i,j)=f(k,i,j)-sumb
    end do
    end do
    end do        these line can create a problem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: One likely cause is that the program is operating on uninitialized data. Maybe one of the input files could not be read, I do not see any status checks for these file reads. Fortran compilers typically have an option that enables symbolic traceback for fatal errors that shows exactly at which source line a program failed, and how program execution to that point. The relevant error output may even be there already, hiding in one of the numerous IDE output windows not opened by default. This output may be easier to catch when operating from the commandline, have you tried that?

Comment: High Performance Mark, where you didn't understand, i can't debug because the program shuts down itself on 64 bit system. I found silverfrost which can work properly on 64 bit, it took less than 2 minutes to find out which line creates a problem. Is it that hard?, I didn't ask an answer. if you have an opinion you can suggest something, if you don't, you don't have to write it.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running it?  If you run from within visual studio using F5, it should stop when the code breaks.

Minor things:
a) Try using higher numbers for output channels.  Most compilers use low numbers like 1, 2, 5, 6 for input to/from console
b) You don't appear to close any channels
c) In subroutine result, you open stream 5 but don't use it at all.
d) If you indent your code instead of starting everything from column 1, it will be slightly easier to read.  eg

```
do i=0,8
   do j=0,8
      sumcc=0.0
      do l=0,8
         sumcc=sumcc+tminv(i,l)*tm(l,j)
      end do
      ev(i,j)=sumcc
   end do
end do
```

e) Normally in VS, floating point exceptions are switched off.  Start up the debugger, put a breakpoint on the first executable line, go to Debug/Exceptions/Win32 exceptions.  Switch on all the floating point exceptions.
f) Conditional breaks in visual studio can be really slow, especially for a 9x101x101 matrix.  You could do something like

```
sumb = sumb + ...
if (sumb .gt. 10000.0) then
   print *,'break here'
end if
```

And set the breakpoint where the print statement is.